# Phonegap starting from Bootstrap / jQuery / PHP

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

the title of my post can seem quite strange.... so I will try to explain what I'm asking.

Consider I'm new to phongap and mobile app development, so be patient.

Actually I'm planning to build a web application, that have some main need
a) Run on desktop and mobile (only tablets, not smartphones) that are connected to internet with quite the same UI
b) access some data needed to initialize application content (like data about categories and products

So my idea (based also on my knowledge) would be to use bootstrap and jquery for web responsive UI, PHP for controllers and data access. In this case I will host application on Apache server and data will be store on Mysql/Maria DB database.

Now the part where I would need your comments and help:
the same web application need to run on tablet that have no internet connection (OFF-LINE).
Here some my idea to make it works in this alternative scenario
1) Use phonegap
2) Use bootstrap and jQuery for UI
Are these points doable or not?

Now 2 other big questions:
- What kind of storage do you suggest to use?
- Can I have one single code and use phonegap to make it run on off-line devices or I will have to build 2 different applications?

I know there are a lot of things inside my question, but pleasse help me with your suggestions to discover the right way.

Kind regards,
Matt

Comment: #Matt You can use SqlLite for the local Storage in devices or You can write data to file E.g Json or text for offline usage.

Comment: Hi @HassanALi, so for your comment it seems that I have to build a version for 'on-line' users, and then transform some part of this one to be able to run off-line. Mainly the parts influenced are data storage and the code that manage it. Is it correct?

Comment: Exactly correct .

Comment: Hi @HassanALi, what kind of framework do you suggest to be used, so that I can optimize the code between off-line mobile app and on-line web-pages?
Second question: is it my idea bootstrap / jQuery a possible way?